# How to use custon iconset in exceljs?

Tags: node.js, exceljs

I'd like to know (an example) how to use custom iconset in exceljs with [addConditionalFormatting](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#conditional-formatting) function.  Also I'm wondering if there is a way to make my own icons and use them with this library.

Thank you in advance.